# Redux one step behind

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have recently used Redux and I notice that every update on `props` seems to be one step behind every time. After the first `dispatch` and `console.log` it returns `null` value but since the second dispatch, it returns the value of the previous and keeps going like that.

Is me making mistake or is it because of Redux? If it is not me, is there some way we can improve this?

**Update**

My mistake to say Redux returns `null`,which is the initial state, it actually returns the state of the previous action. Let say I want to return the state at the moment of action performed.

```
import * as coord from "../actions/coordAction"

function mapStateToProps(store){
    return{
        status: store.coord.status,
        coord:store.coord.coord
    }
}

class Form extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.Submit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let coords=[];
        coords.push(this.refs.xCoord.value);
        coords.push(this.refs.yCoord.value);
        coords.push(this.refs.zCoord.value);

        this.props.dispatch(coord.sendCoord(coords));
        console.log(this.props.coord);
        fetch(/*something*/);

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <form className="coord_form" onSubmit={this.Submit}>
                <input name="xCoord" type="number" ref="xCoord" defaultValue="31" placeholder="xCoord" min="0" max="250" required/>
                <input name="yCoord" type="number" ref="yCoord" defaultValue="31" placeholder="yCoord" min="0" max="250" required/>
                <input name="zCoord" type="number" ref="zCoord" defaultValue="31" placeholder="zCoord" min="0" max="250" required/>
                <button type="submit">send coord</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Form)
```

**store.js**

```
import {applyMiddleware,createStore} from "redux"

import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware"

import coord from "./reducers"

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk);

export default createStore(coord, middleware);
```

**coordReducer.js**

```
export default function reducer(state={
    status:null,
    coord:[]
},action){

    switch(action.type){
        case "GET_COORD":{
            return{
                ...state,
                status: "get",
                coord: [...state.coord,action.payload]
            }
        }
        case "SEND_COORD":{
            return{
                ...state,
                status: "send",
                coord: [...state.coord,action.payload]
            }
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Comment: You need to post some code, that is not the standard behavior

Comment: @rpadovani sorry, my mistake, I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

When you dispatch an action from within a component, the component's props are not immediately updated.  A component update is queued, but React has not yet had a chance to actually apply the updates.  Therefore, all the props are still the same as they were before the dispatch.